# how to use java.util.function in Fluentwait.until in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

```
FluentWait<WebElement> wait2= new FluentWait<WebElement>(table)
            .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    wait2.until(new Function<WebElement,Boolean>(){

        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebElement t) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
```

I have this code, I need to check multiple conditions inside apply for staleness(not included here), ExpectedCondition did not work.

This code gives me error on

```
wait2.until(new Function<WebElement,Boolean>()
```

> The method until(Predicate) in the type FluentWait is not applicable for the arguments (new Function(){})

I am not able to understand the problem, until has two ways:

```
public <V> V until(Function<? super T, V> isTrue)
```

and

```
public void until(final Predicate<T> isTrue)
```

Please if somebody can help me understand this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working , the Function that is used in Fluentwait is

```
com.google.common.base.Function
```

It was not working because I used the java.util.function before.!!

Answer (score 0):

> I tried WebDriverWait instead of FluentWait and it worked for me.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 60);
wait.withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait.pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){
@Override
public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
    WebElement ele=driver.findElement(locator);
    if(ele==null)
        return false;
    else
    {
        System.out.println("WebElement found");
        return true;
    }     
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From this page I saw that new selenium library had removed `com.google.common.base.Function` but take to use `import java.util.function.Function;` which had happened on Jan 23, 2017
see Notes:

```
Update Wait and FluentWait for Java 8
With recent guava release, the Google versions of both
Function and Predicate extend the Java 8 equivalents &
so it's safe for us to make this move. Probably.
```

see this page : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/b2aa9fd534f7afbcba319231bb4bce85f825ef09

Also from official Guava library I saw that in **Guava 21.0** it really had `extends java.util.Function` please notice this change.